# In what situations / circumstances a dynamic_cast<> can fail?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, dynamic-typing

While fixing a bug in a huge code base, I am observing a strange situation, where the dynamic type of a reference changes from Original `Derived` type to `Base` type! I am providing the minimal code to explain the problem:

```
struct Base {
  // some 'virtual' function
  protected: // copy constructor
  private:  // assignment operator
};

struct Derived : Base {
  ... // There are few more classes between `Base` and `Derived`
  ... // but for simplicity, I have put direct relation
};

void foo (Base &ref)
{
  SomeClass obj;
  obj.pVoid = &ref;  // pVoid is of void*

  // ----> typeid(ref) = Derived
  (*funcptr)(obj);
  // ----> typeid(ref) = Base !!!

  Derived *p = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(&ref);  // this fails ... i.e. "p = 0"
}
```

`funcptr` is a function pointer (`void (*)(SomeClass&)`).  `funcptr` can point to so many functions and they have their own call flows, so it would be difficult to debug.

It's very strange that after the call to function pointer, the derived type of `ref` changes from `Derived` to `Base`. To ease my work, I suspected object slicing from `Derived` to `Base`, so I made `~Base()` as pure `virtual` and re-compiled the whole source code. But there was no compiler error, which means that there is no object of `Base` being declared.

What are the potential reasons, that the dynamic type of `ref` `Derived` is changed to `Base` and the `dynamic_cast` fails later on ?

Comment: If the typeid(ref) is base after the call then the function is messing with the object. You are passing a pointer to the object so it would be very easy to write random stuff all over the object.

Comment: @LokiAstari, though this code is stable for several years, what you told is my primary suspect. `pVoid` could be messing it, but I have to see in what circumstances it's happening. Before that, I wanted to check, if I am missing any trivial thing which could alter the dynamic type to static type for a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that the above code is like it actually is because the code example doesn't compile! You cannot implicitly convert a `Base*` resulting from the `dynamic_cast<Base*>(&ref)` to `Derived*`.

That said and assuming that the outputs of the `typeid()` are actually correct there are a few viable explanations of the type ID of the reference changing. All of these indicate an error in the program in some form or the other:

1. The called function destroys the object e.g. by calling the moral equivalent of `dynamics_cast<Base*>(obj.pVoid)->~Base()`.
2. The called function constructs a new object at the address pointed to by `obj.pVoid` using placement `new`, i.e. something like this: `new(obj.pVoid) Base()`.
3. Something is overwriting memory, resulting in leaving a `Base` object in the referenced location.
4. There are probably more reasons...

Personally, I would gamble on the second case being case, i.e. an object is constructed into the location. Obviously, without seeing the function being called it is impossible to tell.

Comment: It was a typo, I have edited to `dynamic_cast<Derived*>(&ref)`. The reason (2) may not be possible, because of the reason, I already mentioned in question. I had made `Base::~Base()` as pure `virtual` and recompiled the code, but there was no compiler error. Which means there is no object creation of `Base` class.

Answer (score 2):

`dynamic_cast` (to a pointer) can return `0` if the conversion is ambiguous. To illustrate:

```
class O {…};
class A : public virtual O {…};
class B : public A {…};
class C : public A {…};
class D : public B, public C {…};


void f(O& p) {
  A* const a(dynamic_cast<A*>(&p));
}

void g() {
  D d;
  f(d);
}
```

Comment: There is no multiple inheritance in this case. Also, even if it would have been there, in my case it won't affect. Because before the function call, the dynamic type of `Base& ref` was `Derived`. So it should have remained as it is.

Comment: @iammilind ok. i will leave it up in case it helps others. thought: perhaps you can add a call to one (or more) of the parameter's virtuals and step through to see what is actually executed to help determine the type (or perhaps expose a memory smasher?). depending on the program you have, it may lead to some clues. reducing visibility (or deleting methods) can also help at times.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for which the `dynamic_cast<>` was failing in my specific case is due to `delete`ing the reference prematurely!

Once a pointer or reference is `delete` + destructed, then any attempt to downcast it to the original type would result in entering the "**undefined behavior**" region. In my case the `dynamic_cast<>` is failing.

```
void foo (Base &ref)
{
  SomeClass obj;
  obj.pVoid = &ref;

  (*funcptr)(obj);  // ----> delete (Base*)(obj.pVoid); in one of the callbacks

  Derived *p = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(&ref);  // fails => "p = 0"
}
```

Comment: @paulm, Yes and it's already mentioned in bold letters in this answer.